# How to control the size of TextInput?

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I am now using bokeh to generate a number of TextInputs which would stack together to construct a 'matrix' so that I can always input numbers to generate new matrices. However, I found that the size of a single TextInput in Bokeh is so big that several TextInputs together would take up a giant space in the tab page, which made the matrix looks so weird and conflicts with other widgets' visual style on the same tag page.

I tried to fix this problem by typing code like: `TextInput(value = '', width = 5)`. However, I just found that the TextInput is still the same size as before, not obeying the width parameter.

Did I do something wrong? Does anyone know how to control the size of the TextInput in Bokeh?

Comment: I would just solve this in Javascript.  I mean, the data will be put on the client anyways, so why not just read the content column count or row count and scale accordingly?

Comment: @Fallenreaper So, you mean creating the matrix by using Javascript, rather than Bokeh? But I am really new to javascript. So, Bokeh is still the first priority.

Comment: I too have encountered this problem.  At this time (version 0.12.11), it appears that the TextInput widget does not yet have a width attribute.

Comment: @b2002 Yes, I agree. I have found 2 suggestions on how to fix this. You may check [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6427) and [another GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4636) where some people give solutions on how to fix that by using CSS.

Comment: @b2002 I also suggest you vote for my post so that more people can see this problem.

Comment: As of version 0.12.6 there is not a height attribute either.  I think the sizing of the TextInput is planned for either 0.12.7 or 0.12.8

Comment: @b2002 I hope so. It would be strange if they keep this little problem for a quite long time.